# Does anyone know from which game this screenshot is?

Tags: game-identification

[image: Game screenshot]

I stumbled upon this screenshot recently and was wondering which game this was.
Anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's [Head Soccer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dnddream.headsoccer.android&gl=US), a mobile game developed by D&D Dream also playable on browser, the screenshot below is very similar:

[image]

Comment: You are correct, in the way that it is head soccer. But it was played on a Mac and not mobile.

Comment: Indeed, I wrote it's also playable on browser